# Beguiling Gift with Suits of Armor. Is there a way to make it work? What are the logistics of it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Let's say that I want to inhibit a Mage for as long as possible by forcing them to don a suit of armor and then either wear it for the rest of the battle or waste even more time getting out of it. This means Spell Failure, Check Penalties, etc. and at least 5 rounds of wasted time (Chain shirt donned hastily).

Beguiling Gift uses a "gift" as a focus, urging the target to don the item for the duration. Once the duration ends, it has no obligation to keep using it, which is a shame because the duration is 1 round. With Extend Spell, we get 2 rounds out of it.

### Question 1:

**Is there a way to further increase the duration of Beguiling Gift?**

---

Now, let's say that we instead of using a chainshirt which takes between 10 rounds and 5 rounds to put on, we get really ambitious and offer our target a full suit of armor, which takes 4 minutes to don no matter how you slice it (without help).

### Question 2:

**What penalties does someone suffer from wearing a partially-donned suit of armor?**

### Question 3:

**How long does it take to remove a partially-donned suit of armor given that you've spent X rounds donning it?**

---

One last thing. Probably the only way I can think of making this work. This is a little tangent to the spell and the armor logic, but it's related to the entire "scheme".

### Question 4:

**Can a cursed suit of armor urge someone to finish putting it on once they've started until it's fully donned?**

Comment: I think for most bards one of the problems with the scheme might be carrying around the extra 25-lb. chain shirt. Also, have you already considered and rejected the more prosaic [*charm person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It's not very hard to carry around loads of things in Pathfinder. There are so many sources of carrying capacity and there are plenty of extra- and non-dimenional spaces to put things. The objective is to work with Beguiling Gift. I plan to use this in an existing and currently running campaign where I'm playing a 7 Charisma Face Wizard. Opposed Charisma checks are not an option for me.

Comment: I propose an edit to the question.  Would it make sense to change it to: "What is the most effective way to use Beguiling Gift in combat?"  That leaves open the notion of giving people armors, but it also allows gifts such as manacles (for casters) and steel shields (for druids).

Comment: @DanB O, man. That gift-a-steel-shield-to-a-druid thing is cruel ("A druid who... uses a prohibited shield is unable to cast druid spells or use any of her supernatural or spell-like class abilities while doing so and for 24 hours thereafter").

Comment: @DanB That wouldn't make for a very good question (it's effectively "come up with arbitrary effective ways to use beguiling gift"), but it sounds like a brilliant candidate for a [[meta-tag:just-for-fun]] request. It'd be a pretty funny competition of one-upping each other

Comment: @doppelgreener Beguiling Gifting someone a legal contract and pen to learn their name and earn their power of attorney. Beguiling Gifting someone the Girdle of Genderbending and then an age-reducing cursed item to send them through puberty. This would definitely be a fun [tag:just-for-fun].

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I don't know of any way to further increase the duration of your spell (past what you get with Extend Spell).

Can't you just give your target a manacles?  Even a crappy generic manacles has DCs well above 20 to get out of, and it will shut down all spells with somatic components ([citation](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r55o?Do-manacles-prevent-a-sorcerer-from-casting)).  This will work on fighter-types too (and you'll have a much easier time getting past their Will save).